# How to deny maven to use open projects in Eclipse instead of jar from repository

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, dependencies, m2eclipse

Currently if i have dependency project opened, then maven use it instead of specified jar from repo.

Is there Eclipse  setting (or conf for pom), so maven will always use specified dependencies non-regarding if corresponding project opened or not in eclipse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using m2eclipse, **right-click** on your project and go to **Properties > Maven** and disable **Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects**.